# Display and edit last item in a table

Tags: vba, excel

I built a table that keeps track of items I order online. It stores the name of the item and corresponding information (quantity ordered, pieces included, date ordered, date shipped, shipping status, source of purchase), and assigns each item an ID.

There is a button next to the table where I can click and select whether to add a new item to the list or edit an existing items information (shipping status, etc). I am able to add a new item to the list, and I am able to edit the information for all but the last item in the table.

When I select an item to edit, the userform displays the corresponding information. This works for every item in my table except the last item, item #55 which displays the same information as the last item selected, or nothing at all if selected first.

I have tried manually clearing each cell and then using the form to re-add the items, they are added correctly but the information still does not display when I try to edit.

In the code below the subroutine for the delete button is commented out, if anyone has suggestions on what I need to do here to get this working, that would be appreciated as well but I will start a new question for that in the future if I need to.

The real problem is getting the last two items to display the correct information when selected.

Here is the code for editing an existing item:

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub cboOrderedFrom2_Change()

    cboOrderedFrom2.BackColor = vbWhite
    lblOrderedFrom2.ForeColor = vbBlack

End Sub


Private Sub cboOrderStatus2_Change()

    cboOrderedFrom2.BackColor = vbWhite
    lblOrderStatus2.ForeColor = vbBlack

End Sub


Private Sub cboItem_Change()

    cboItem.BackColor = vbWhite
    lblItemDescription2.ForeColor = vbBlack

    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Integer, wsLR As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    wsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Rows

    For i = 3 To wsLR

        If ws.Cells(i, 2) = Me.cboItem Then
            Me.txtItemID.Value = ws.Cells(i, "A")
            Me.txtPiecesIncluded2.Value = ws.Cells(i, "C")
            Me.txtOrderDate2.Value = ws.Cells(i, "E")
            Me.cboOrderStatus2.Value = ws.Cells(i, "G")
            Me.txtQuantityOrdered2.Value = ws.Cells(i, "D")
            Me.txtDateShipped2.Value = ws.Cells(i, "F")
            Me.cboOrderedFrom2.Value = ws.Cells(i, "H")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

End Sub


Private Sub cmdAddStore_Click()

    frmAddStore.Show

End Sub


Private Sub cmdCancelEditOrRemoveItemDetails_Click()

    Unload Me

End Sub


'Private Sub cmdRemoveItemDetails_Click()

    'Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Integer, wsLR As Variant

    'Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'wsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Rows

    'For i = 3 To wsLR

        'If ws.Cells(i, 2) = Me.cboItem Then
            'Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            'Sheet1.Activate
            'Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
            'ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value + 1
            'Unload Me
        'End If

    'Next i

'End Sub

Private Sub cmdSubmitEditItemDetails_Click()

    If txtPiecesIncluded2.BackColor = vbRed Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If txtQuantityOrdered2.BackColor = vbRed Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If cboOrderStatus2.BackColor = vbRed Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If cboOrderedFrom2.BackColor = vbRed Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If cboItem.Value = "" Then
        cboItem.BackColor = vbRed
        lblItemDescription2.ForeColor = vbRed
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If cboItem.BackColor = vbRed Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Integer, wsLR As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    wsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Rows

    For i = 3 To wsLR

        If ws.Cells(i, "B") = Me.cboItem Then
            ws.Cells(i, "A") = Me.txtItemID.Value
            ws.Cells(i, "C") = Me.txtPiecesIncluded2.Value
            ws.Cells(i, "E") = Me.txtOrderDate2.Value
            ws.Cells(i, "G") = Me.cboOrderStatus2.Value
            ws.Cells(i, "D") = Me.txtQuantityOrdered2.Value
            ws.Cells(i, "F") = Me.txtDateShipped2.Value
            ws.Cells(i, "H") = Me.cboOrderedFrom2.Value
            Unload Me
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

End Sub


Private Sub spnPiecesIncluded2_Change()

    txtPiecesIncluded2.Value = spnPiecesIncluded2.Value

End Sub


Private Sub spnQuantityOrdered2_Change()

    txtQuantityOrdered2.Value = spnQuantityOrdered2.Value

End Sub


Private Sub txtPiecesIncluded2_Change()

    If IsNumeric(txtPiecesIncluded2.Value) And txtPiecesIncluded2.Value >= spnPiecesIncluded2.Min And _
    txtPiecesIncluded2.Value <= spnPiecesIncluded2.Max Then
        spnPiecesIncluded2.Value = txtPiecesIncluded2.Value
        txtPiecesIncluded2.BackColor = vbWhite
        lblPiecesIncluded2.ForeColor = vbBlack
    Else
        txtPiecesIncluded2.BackColor = vbRed
        lblPiecesIncluded2.ForeColor = vbRed
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub txtQuantityOrdered2_Change()

    If IsNumeric(txtQuantityOrdered2.Value) And txtQuantityOrdered2.Value >= spnQuantityOrdered2.Min And _
    txtQuantityOrdered2.Value <= spnQuantityOrdered2.Max Then
        spnQuantityOrdered2.Value = txtQuantityOrdered2.Value
        txtQuantityOrdered2.BackColor = vbWhite
        lblQuantityOrdered2.ForeColor = vbBlack
    Else
        txtQuantityOrdered2.BackColor = vbRed
        lblQuantityOrdered2.ForeColor = vbRed
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: `wsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row `. That was the first thing I noticed, but there's a lot of code there (too much really)

Comment: @Tim Williams Thanks for looking at my mess of a post! I know there's a lot of code here to look through. As for the line you pointed out, what exactly is wrong with it? I have been scrutinising that exact part of the code for a while now because I think this is where my problem is coming from. The wsLR is defined as Variant rather than Range like I think it should be, but when I define it as Range then I get an error and the debug starts and highlights that exact line that you pointed out. But as it is, it works for all but the last item in the list. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Please note the difference between your `wsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Rows` and `wsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` which @Tim Williams suggested. `Rows` is a collection of all rows in a range - in your case only the last filled row - and assigned to a `Variant`, it will be the **value** of the first cell in that row. But `Row` is the row number -in your case the row number of the last filled row - and this is what you probably need.

Comment: From how you've used it in the loop, seems like wsLR should be defined as Long.  Edit: what @AxelRichter said...

Comment: @Alex Richter @ Tim Williams Thanks Alex for pointing that out! I did not notice the Row vs Rows, this fixed the Issue. And I changed the wsLR to As Long, thanks you both so much for your help!!!